# surfaceview gives darker shade

Tags: android, colors, surfaceview

I am new to graphics and surfaceviews etc. I have heard that it is better to draw on a seperate thread than on the main thread. i have 2 activities one which is drawn using ondraw of the view, the other uses surface view. both have the same code for drawing. however the latter gives a much darker backgroung color-even at max alpha setting(255). If I comment out the drawargb line I get a black background. I tried many things like setting background color of surfaceview object and setting pixelformat to rgb888 or transparent but none of these work.Following is the code:

```
SurfaceHolder ourHolder;Boolean isRunning=true;
Thread ourThread;ArrayList<Float> amtint=new ArrayList();float max;
String names[];String company;
public GraphSview(Context c) {
    super(c);
ourHolder=getHolder();

ourThread=new Thread(this);
ourThread.start();}
public void pause(){
isRunning=false;
while(true){try {
    ourThread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}break;}ourThread=null;
}

public void Resume()
{
 isRunning=true;
ourThread=new Thread(this);
ourThread.start();}
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(isRunning){
if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())continue;
Canvas canvas=ourHolder.lockCanvas();
canvas.drawARGB(255, 33, 181, 238);
....  ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

code for the main activity is

```
public class GraphS extends Activity{
GraphSview ourSview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ourSview=new GraphSview(this);
    ourSview.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    setContentView(ourSview);
    //ourSview.setBackgroundColor(0Xffffffff);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    ourSview.pause();
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
ourSview.Resume();  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

   }
```

is there something wrong with the code?
is there any alternate way of creating and displaying graphs other than surface view?

Comment: I put a rectangle bmp of required color using bitmapfactory etc. and put it over the whole of the screen, so it solved the problem